# How do I change my material's shader property at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, materials

I have a material whose shader has a opacity property which I want to change at runtime. How do I get the reference to that property.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done via [`Material.SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html).

You'll need to use the actual property **reference name** as key, not the Inspector display name, e.g.

[image]

Comment: I was using the name. The reference name was different  Thanks for the help.